# How do I handle a deadlock due to a child process abruptly terminating?

Tags: c, process, deadlock

I currently have code that creates a child process that runs a Java program that writes to a file. The parent process repeatedly calls ReadFile until it either returns an error or reads 0 bytes, i.e. code like this:

```
while (1) {
    if( !ReadFile( handle, buf, bufsize, &dwRead, NULL) 
        || dwRead == 0) break;

    // do stuff with bytes read
}
```

However, when the Java program encounters an error and subsequently writes to the file about the exception it caught, my parent process reads the exception and apparently goes into a deadlock waiting for more input from the file.

How do I write code that prevents this scenario from ever happening? Assume that I cannot change the Java program. Do I wait for the child process to finish before doing this processing? Do I add another clause in the if-statement to check that the child process is still running? Any other alternatives?

Comment: You are probably going to need to show us the code that opens the file in the C code.  Normally, when the Java process finishes (whether it is under control or crashing at the time), the file will be a fixed size and your C program will get zero bytes to read when it reaches the end.  If your program is not handling that as EOF (for example, it goes to sleep for a while, wakes up and tries to read more data), then you will have to decide how long to wait for more input before giving up — assume the file won't change again.  We may also need to see `ReadFile()` code.

Comment: You mention `handle` and use `dwRead`; are you running on Unix-like systems, or on Windows systems, or on both — or what?  That can be important information; the answers are probably different for Windows and Unix.  Even on Unix, the answer for Linux may be different from the answer for AIX, BSD, HP-UX, Mac OS X, Solaris, etc (and there may be differences between any pair of those systems).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler This is on Windows so ReadFile is one of its File Management functions. How would I wait for more input before giving up?

Comment: No idea — I don't know the Windows API at all (witness the fact that I didn't recognize `ReadFile` as a Windows function).  There are manuals online at Microsoft's MSDN.  That's where I'd have to go to find out — but you have a vested interest in finding out and I'm sorry but I don't.  On Unix, using file descriptors, you pause briefly, then try again.  Using file streams (`FILE *`), you have to clear the error/EOF state (`clearerr(fp)`) as well before you retry.  I don't know whether that applies on Windows.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into a parallel of that for Windows!